# In what way would windows appease or calm us?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, french-language, gaetan-roussel, alain-bashung

Alain Bashung's song [Sur un trapèze](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sN4vBuQNGw), with lyrics by Gaëtan Roussel 
(see the Wikipedia article about the [album *Bleu pétrole*, released in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleu_p%C3%A9trole)),
begins with the following lines (emphasis and links added)

> On dirait qu'on sait lire sur les lèvres
>   Et que l'on tient tous les deux sur un [trapèze](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap%C3%A8ze_(agr%C3%A8s))
>   On dirait que sans les poings on est toujours aussi [balèzes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bal%C3%A8ze)
>   **Et que les fenêtres nous [apaisent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/apaiser)**

Translation (if I understand the words correctly):

> One would say that we can lipread
>   And that we can stand (?) together on a trapeze
>   One would say that without our wrist we would still be equally strong
>   
> And that the windows pacify / calm us

In what way would windows do this?
(Living in confined spaces, *behind windows*, has not been doing many people a lot of good from a psychological point of view.) Or is Roussel being ironic here?

Comment: You'd better provide the full lyrics in the question. Poetry is not easy to interpret and analyse even if the full context is given - let alone just a couple of random lines...

Comment: @tum_ The full lyrics are copyrighted, so they can't be reproduced in full here, but you can find them in one of the comments below the YouTube video I referenced.